# Why c++(g++) allows no spacing between template return type and function name?

Tags: c++, function, templates, g++

I'm wondering why below syntax is allowed with g++
Does someone has an idea why this works well?

If you see below sample code there is no spacing between `Base<int>` and `foo()`
but It is still OK with g++

```
template<typename T>
class Base {};

Base<int>foo()
{
    cout << "Hello World" << endl;
}

int main()
{
    foo();
}
```

Comment: Why are expecting a space to be between `>` and `f`? The space helps with readability but is not required. It is no different than not having spaces in expressions like `a+b==c-7`.

Comment: This is no different from a function returning a pointer, which also doesn't need a space: `int*foo() { ... }`. You need a space in `int main()` because without the space, the lexer can't tell where the `int` token ends.

Answer (score 3):

Identifiers tokens cannot include `<` or `>`, so the space is optional. Read up on [tokenization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lexical_analysis#Tokenization).